# Object.prototype.toString.call()

Tags: object, prototype

`Object.prototype.toString.call([1,2,3])
"[object Array]"`

`[1,2,3].toString()
"1,2,3"`

Why is the first statement returns `"[object Array]"` rather than "1,2,3"?